# How I can connect my webapp with Azure AD B2C

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to set up my asp.net core with a web app. But I am running into errors. I did some googling and found possible solutions like

[documentation on making an ASP.NET Core web app with Azure AD B2C]
(https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/) and this [.NETCore B2C sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp)

In the solution for the sample, the `appsettings.json` file also has the Api.

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
"ClientId": "90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6",
"Tenant": "fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
"SignUpSignInPolicyId": "b2c_1_susi",
"ResetPasswordPolicyId": "b2c_1_reset",
"EditProfilePolicyId": "b2c_1_edit_profile",
"RedirectUri": "http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc",
"ClientSecret" : "v0WzLXB(uITV5*Aq",
"ApiUrl": "https://fabrikamb2chello.azurewebsites.net/hello",
"ApiScopes": "https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/helloapi/demo.read"
}
```

But I don’t understand why I need the Api. Do I need to just set up the API in my Azure AD B2C Tennant? Or there must some code inside in the Api that I need as well?

Is there a good example which I can use to help understand the topic?

Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend reading through the ReadMe on the [.NetCore webapp sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp), and running the sample as-is first.

Then, follow the `[OPTIONAL]` steps, which explain how the sample works and how to set it up using your own B2C tenant and policies. The sample calls an API `"https://fabrikamb2chello.azurewebsites.net/hello"`, so here you'd need to [register your own Web API with B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications#register-a-web-api) so you can define the scopes that you will request access tokens for.

Then you will replace your app coordinates with the ones in the sample (ex. Tenant, ClientId, Policies, ClientSecret, ApiUrl, and ApiScopes). Finally, you should be able to rebuild and run the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jenny for your help.

At step 4 in the

> [OPTIONAL] Step 4: Create your own Web API This sample calls an API at
>   https://fabrikamb2chello.azurewebsites.net which has the same code as
>   the sample Node.js Web API with Azure AD B2C. You'll need your own API
>   or at the very least, you'll need to register a Web API with Azure AD
>   B2C so that you can define the scopes that your single page
>   application will request access tokens for. Your web API registration
>   should include the following information: Enable the Web App/Web API
>   setting for your application. Set the Reply URL to the appropriate
>   value indicated in the sample or provide any URL if you're only doing
>   the web api registration, for example https://myapi. Make sure you
>   also provide a AppID URI, for example demoapi, this is used to
>   construct the scopes that are configured in you single page
>   application's code. (Optional) Once you're app is created, open the
>   app's Published Scopes blade and add any extra scopes you want. Copy
>   the AppID URI and Published Scopes values, so you can input them in
>   your application's code.

I can set up the WebAPI in my Azure B2C Tennant. 
What is the code for the API? Or is it just fine when I set up the WebAPI in the Azure B2C tenant?

Comment: You'll have to register the API with Azure AD B2C [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications#register-a-web-api).

Comment: Sorry my question. But only register and not any Code behind?

Comment: you'll have to add certain values from the api registration to the appsettings.json of the project...like: 
`"ApiUrl": "https://fabrikamb2chello.azurewebsites.net/hello",
  "ApiScopes": "https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/helloapi/demo.read"`

Comment: Yes, but behind: https://fabrikamb2chello.azurewebsites.net/hello there must be any function or just en empty url.

Comment: The AppUrl is the identifier used for the web api, which is generated for you. See this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-web-api). Then you can configure the scopes.

Comment: Sorry - I know this is an old post, but I started looking into this too. downloaded the ios sample and I too am somewhat confused


@Stefan did you manage to get it working.

I wish there was an end - to - end tutorial including front and backend with explanation of each step (without jumping from between multiple docs and tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help. Now the authentication with Azure AD B2C runs. 
How I can inside the controller check if the user is signed in?
When the user signed in then do some stuff. If the user not signed in only show the sign in button. 
I know how I check it inside in the view but not in the controller.